# Sharepoint 2007 - List ID Function

Tags: sharepoint

I have read many posts that say the automatically assigned list ID number in Sharepoint 2007 does not change.
It is very important that the list items in my sharepoint site stay in the same order as when they were originally created.  My initial image was that I could sort on the ID # to keep the list in order (since it wasn't supposed to change).  It has not worked out. I have noticed that the ID changes and my data gets out of order.

Could anyone please explain to me how the automatically assigned ID # works in Sharepoint 2007? How/When is it assigned, reassigned? Is there an action that causes the # to change? 
When a workflow runs does Sharepoint reassign the item w another ID#? I do have several workflows running on this site.

Comment: I've never seen it change. Are you SURE that it is?

Answer (score 1):

A list item id is just like a SQL identity column. It is automatically incremented, is (or should be) unique within a particular list and doesn't change. Are you able to identify a point in your process where you are seeing an id change?

Comment: It has something to do with rebuilding/syncing.  I am still trying to replicate it.  I believe I am going to have to create a new column and either manually enter a value or run a workflow to add a value...not sure how I want to do it yet.

Comment: What kind of workflows do you have running? The id really shouldn't change unless the list items are being re-created for some reason... and I'm not sure why you'd do that.

Comment: The workflows are not related to the ID field.  However, I believe that at some point my list has rebuilt and reassigned new ID numbers.  I am assuming that a rebuild would recognize items as new and renumber.  During development of this sight, there were ....issues. I am not going to try to replicate the situation since I can't pin point the environmental conditions and the person who did it.  Just to make sure and since the unique order is so important, I will replicate the ID in another field and sort off of that until I get comfortable again.  Thank you for reponding to my post.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can take a look at the back-end sql server, there is no way you can manupilate it on user interface or object model as i know.